# ffmpeg Permission denied on java

Tags: java, ffmpeg, ubuntu-16.04

Getting an error:

```
"java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
"/home/dijo/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg": error=13, Permission denied"
```

When I use

```
FFmpeg ffmpeg = new FFmpeg("/home/dijo/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg")
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Is the `ffmpeg` file you're pointing to a binary (the fact it's in ffmpeg_sources makes me think it may not be), and if so has it got executable permissions for your user / group? (If you're not sure, try running `ls -l /home/dijo/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg` in a shell and paste the output.)

Comment: berry thank you for your reply, actually, "/home/dijo/bin/ffmpeg" this is the path i have used frst. while using this path i got the error

Comment: java.io.IOException: /home/dijo/bin/ffmpeg returned non-zero exit status. Check stdout.

Comment: What library are you using for FFmpeg? And does the error still occur on that line (when you're creating the ffmpeg object?)

Comment: the error is throwing when I run the project

Comment: how should I find the path for ffmpeg?am I using the correct path?

Comment: It's thrown when you run the project, but one what *line* is it thrown? The one given or another one?

Comment: yes it's throwing error when creating the ffmpeg object

Comment: And the FFmpeg library that you're using is..?

Comment: compile_ffmpeg.md

Comment: That's just an old, outdated, and expired ripoff of [FFmpeg Wiki: Compile on Ubuntu & Debian](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu). It would have been nice if they provided attribution (as it is licensed CC BY-SA 3.0) instead of just copying and pasting it.

Comment: hi loardNeck, I have removed the old version an installed the updated version from the above link. but still when i check "ffmpeg -version" i am getting message "ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libx265.so.158: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Comment: hi lordNeck, updating ffmpeg works for me. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

installing ffmpeg from  https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu has solved the error. After following these steps

ffmpeg path will be - /usr/bin/ffmpeg

an dffprobe path will be - /usr/bin/ffprobe